# suppressing messages to standard output from package morewrites

Tags: tex-core, terminal-output, morewrites

I have to use `morewrites` and I do not like the fact that it writes to standardout since I miss other messages. Is it possible to suppress the messages concerning `.mw`? That is `[1] (./debug-morewrites.mw) [2]`? (./debug-morewrites.mw

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{morewrites}


\begin{document}

Test.

\pagebreak

Test.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Those messages seem to come from `\iow_shipout_x` which is connected to the page shipout. I don't know whether those messages are removable

Comment: they come from tex-the-program so unless you recode morewrites not to input the file the `(...)` has to be in the log. You can of course stop it from being on the terminal by `\batchmode` or similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(...)` comes from tex-the-program so unless you recode `morewrites` not to input the file the `(...)` has to be in the log. You can however stop it from being on the terminal by locally switching to `\batchmode` something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{morewrites}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__morewrites_shipout_ii:
  {
    \__morewrites_before_shipout:
    \__morewrites_tex_shipout:w \tex_box:D \g__morewrites_shipout_box
    \edef\tmp{\interactionmode\the\interactionmode\space}\batchmode\__morewrites_after_shipout:\tmp
  }


\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

Test.

\pagebreak

Test.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\exp_args:NNx \batchmode \__morewrites_after_shipout: {\interactionmode\the\interactionmode}`

Comment: @egreg I am sure there are `_` names for `\batchmode` , `\interactionmode` and `\the`, to complete the story:-)

Comment: Does not work for me. Texlive 2017: (./debug-morewrites.aux) [1] (./debug-morewrites.mw) [2] (./debug-morewrites.mw
) (./debug-morewrites.aux) )
Output written on debug-morewrites.dvi (2 pages, 320 bytes).

Comment: @StefanMüller are you looking at the terminal output or the log?

Comment: Terminal output. Log would be fine, but I do not want to see these messages in the terminal.

Comment: Can we give this another try? It does not work on texlive 2020 for me. I also tried @egreg's suggestion. Probably the wrong way. Maybe egreg can put this into a separate solution. Thanks!

Comment: @StefanMüller thisalways worked if you did what was in my head. As you say it didn't work I assume that you did what I posted in the answer, which never worked.  The first line had   `\cs_set_protected:Npn \__lmorewrites_shipout_ii:`  with a completely spurious `l` before the `morewrites`  this is removed in the edit I just made, sorry:-)

Comment: You made my day! Thank you. So much less to read from now on. =:-)

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of the entries in the log as well? With extensive usage, the file is bloated with messages like `\openout3 = \`debug-morewrites.mw'.`

Comment: Or is it maybe possible to exclude specific output streams from handling by `morewrites`?

Answer (score 2):

Well, what you want to do is to filter the output written by TeX to
stdout; this is not a special implementation for the package morewrites.
I use Karl Berry's [texfot](https://ctan.org/pkg/texfot) when I want the terminal to show
only certain messages. It is a Perl script. It can be customized and
it has several options although from the description you gave the
standard settings seem to be already helpful for you.

Comment: Cool. Did not know this. I used grep in a pipe to reach similar effects. Keeping page numbers displayed would be good. Maybe I will figure out how to do this while looking at the source code of texfot.

Comment: A page number is not placed on its own line, so a line with a page number contains additional unwanted text too. More a guess than a tested solution: Add `|.*\[[1-9].*\]` in the list for showing, for example, after the `|No\ pages\ of\ output`. (It should work even with page numbers that output several registers.)

Comment: Thanks! But this is for the `langsci` package and all users should have a solution. Telling them to call tex with a different program would not work, I guess.